# No ConnectionProviderFactory in Hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate, migration

I'm migrating a project from hibernate 3.6.5 to hibernate 4.
Spotted that there is no `ConnectionProviderFactory` class in new one.

Can somebody explain where has it gone?

It is neither deprecated in 3.6 nor present in 3.6 -> 4 migration docs.

**UPDATE:**
I've figured out what happened with `ConnectionProviderFactory`. It is now `ConnectionProviderInitiator`. So CDI is good but factories are still present.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate 4 gets a major version upgrade because it's significantly different from the Hibernate 3.x series. If you are looking for an official explanation for why the class is missing you will probably have to hunt down one of the dev's in their IRC channel, but they do  describe alot of their design decisions on their [blog](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/HibernateCore400Alpha1Released).

Afaict, this class was removed because Hibernate 4 is integrated with CDI, you really do not need Factory classes anymore. You can simply inject a connection provider:

```
@Inject
private ConnectionProvider provider;
```

I would highly recommend you take a look at using JPA 2, instead of accessing Hibernate 4 libraries directly.

Comment: Using CDI instead of factories is very reasonable. It's a pity but such a cardinal switch from hibernate to jpa is practically impossible in a big project. Thanks for the answer